# How to change the DLL name in the already compiled application?

Tags: disassembly, dll, patch-reversing, reassembly, .net

I am trying to change the name of the DLL file I had specified for my application before compiling it. When I change the DLL file name I get the error message like:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyDLLName'
```

Is there any way to change the DLL I had specified through .NET Reflector + Reflexil add-in?

Comment: Okay, I'll ask the blatantly obvious. Why not simply recompile?

Comment: @Jongware Because I have lost the source code! Please don't ask me to rewrite the program!!!

Comment: @FreeMind The next time, consider using source control and some code hosting.

Comment: Well, you seem to think that Reflexil might do it. Have you tried it? How did it fail?

Comment: @svick I just do not know how to change the name of the imported DLL file in Reflexil.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the fact that there was no answer to the question posed for so long, I decided to add it:

**Briefly:**

use

[reflector](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) and

[reflexil](http://reflexil.net/), [active fork](https://github.com/sailro/Reflexil)

to change this

**Full answer:**

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2543519d-1fa1-4ee3-a169-c5718cc11f5e/changing-the-name-of-a-dll?forum=csharplanguage

[webarchived](https://web.archive.org/web/20221225181415/https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2543519d-1fa1-4ee3-a169-c5718cc11f5e/changing-the-name-of-a-dll?forum=csharplanguage)